# Graphic programming in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, sqlite, graphic

I save the data from USB into the database sqlite3 and I want to create a wave of these datas, I prefer to use C in Linux, maybe another language is also ok. Anyone has an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't know USB and Sqlite3 is considered graphics programming... I always learn something new on StackOverflow...

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++ then checkout QT, has its open graphics library and supports OpenGL too

Comment: And with C, you can use GTK, which has also an OpenGL extension